# when refresh browser page and countdown timer should not continue

Tags: javascript

**View:**

```
    <div class="box-body">
        <h2><p style="float: right" id="countdown"></p></h2>
    </div>

<script>
  $time_limit = $("#time_limit").val();      //2016-08-14 00:10:00
    var d = new Date($time_limit);
    var hours = d.getHours();                  //00 hours
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();              //10 minutes
    var seconds = 60 * minutes;                // 600seconds

    function secondPassed() {
        var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);
        console.log(minutes);
        var hours = Math.round((minutes) / 60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(myVar);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Time Out";
        } else {
            seconds--;
            console.log(seconds);
        }

    }
    var myVar = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);

</script>
```

[image]

MY Question: When i browser page refresh and countdown timer should not continue, i click next button and browser page refresh and countdown timer should not continue .......................................................

Comment: Tell me when it should start counting ?

Comment: @Nandan First View Quiz Screenshot and then i click next button and page refresh and timer should not continue, but timer reset ,why ? help me..

Comment: If I understand correctly, your problem is that the timer is reseted after each browser refresh? This is because you do not persist the time taken. If you want the time to be saved between browser refreshes you need to save the time taken either in a cookie or in a localstorage. You can get further information on this topic on the html5 help page [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: can't see any thing to do with codeigniter here.

Comment: @ Stefan Kert I don't know how to use localstorage in mycode,so please write mycode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (typeof(Storage) == "undefined") 
{
    alert("Your browser does not support web storage");
    //Abort the script;
    //throw new Error("Something went badly wrong!");
}


$time_limit = $("#time_limit").val();
var d = new Date($time_limit);
var hours = d.getHours();                  //00 hours
var minutes = d.getMinutes();              //10 minutes
var seconds = 60 * minutes;
if (localStorage.getItem("seconds") !== null) 
{
    seconds = localStorage.getItem("seconds");
}



function secondPassed() 
{
            var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);
            console.log(minutes);
            var hours = Math.round((minutes) / 60);
            var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
            if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
                remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
            }
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
            if (seconds == 0) {
                clearInterval(myVar);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Time Out";
            } else {
                seconds--;
                console.log(seconds);
            }
            localStorage.setItem("seconds",seconds);
}

var myVar = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for myhelp

Answer (score 0):

If you need persistance for this case you need to save the data in to the localstorage for the browser, because otherwise it always gets cleared after a refresh. I´ve prepared an example. You can find it here:

[Countdown with Storage](https://jsfiddle.net/xLmeagLo/)

The necessary Code pieces are the following:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") { // checks if localStorage is enabled
   if (localStorage.seconds) {         // checks if seconds are saved to localstorage
      seconds = localStorage.seconds;  // grabs the data from localstorage
   }
}
```

With this piece of code you get the data initially from the localstorage. I´ve placed it above your function so it gets invoked imediately after setting everything for startup.

The other part is, to save the data. This piece of code is responsible for this purpose:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
   localStorage.setItem("seconds", seconds);
}
```

You again check if the Storage is available for you and then you set seconds to the disred value.

The last step is to clear the localstorage after the time has expired:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  localStorage.removeItem("seconds");
}
```

Again, checking if Storage exists and then remove the item with the name seconds. Another possibility would be to check one time if Storage exists and either tell the user that the data is not persistet or work with cookies.

Comment: Thank you so much for myhelp

Comment: i have diffrent exam and diffrent test and diffrent time ,and any exam click then timer should continue why?

Comment: Because it is saved in the localstorage. You need to reset it for a new test. Probably you can delete the storage if you click "Start Test" or something similar. Is there a starting point in your Test? Or can you verify if the user switches test, or exam? Then you need to clear the items like showed in my answer. `localstorage.removeItem("seconds");`

Comment: @ Stefan Kert you give me online examination system script using codeigniter or php

Comment: I do not understand what you want from me, but probably you could give me some upvotes `cause my answers where pretty decent ;). Can you explain to me what you like to have?

Comment: @ Stefan Kert  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39016093/how-to-exam-wise-countdown-timer-start                                                              view above link

Comment: @ Stefan Kert How to calculate hour,minutes,second

Comment: like(01:10:00) how to calculate hour,minutes,seconds