# How to exam wise countdown timer start

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create online examination system and i create different exam and different time assign ,i click any exam accroding to countdown timer start, 
see below screenshot

ScreenShot-1

[image]

Screenshot-2

[image]

**View:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="time_limit" id="time_limit" value="<?php echo $examination_test_result['time_limit']; ?>">

<div class="box-body">
    <h2><p style="float: right" id="countdown"></p></h2>

<script>

     $time_limit = $("#time_limit").val();
        var d = new Date($time_limit);
        var hours = d.getHours();
        var minutes = d.getMinutes();
        var seconds = 60 * minutes;

        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {      //checks if localStorage is enabled
            if (localStorage.seconds) {                       //checks if seconds are saved to localstorage
                seconds = localStorage.seconds;
            }
        }
        function secondPassed() {
            var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);
            var hours = Math.round((minutes) / 60);
            var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
            if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
                remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
            }

            if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
                localStorage.setItem("seconds", seconds);

            }
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;

            if (seconds == 0) {
                clearInterval(myVar);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = alert('Timeout');
                window.location.href = base_url + "student/Examinations";

                if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
                    localStorage.removeItem("seconds");
                }
            } else {
                seconds--;
            }

        }
        var myVar = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

MY Question: I click different exam and examwise countdown timer start.             but i have problem i click any exam and countdown timer continue

Comment: I did not get the last line ... can you please make it more clear what is your problem and what you want?

Comment: Please post your full code. Cannot reproduce the issue in our side.

Comment: @Moumit first see above screenshot and after i click basic maths then countdow timer start and after click basic gujarati then countdown timer does not start but previous countdown timer continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in another thread, you need to remove the countdown from the LocalStorage. To achieve this you need to perform this action on an defined event, like a button click, or whatever.

```
function resetCountdownInLocalStorage(){
    localStorage.removeItem("seconds");
}
```

You can call this action, like I mentioned on for example the click event of your "Next" button, or on every Restart of the test.

For example if you want to call this action on your Next button and we assume that the button has the Id `next` you can achieve the requested action by using this javascript snippet:

```
document.getElementById("next").onclick = function() {       
     localStorage.removeItem("seconds");
}
```

Or using the function from above:

```
 document.getElementById("next").onclick = resetCountdownInLocalStorage;
```

Comment: thank yoy for my help

Answer (score 0):

From your question i think you want a set of timers that will work independently. I have created an example. Please check this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/42/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="timer" started="false" timerObj="" value="10">
Start Timer
<div id="timer1"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="timer" started="false" timerObj="" value="10">
Start Timer
<div id="timer2"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="timer" started="false" timerObj="" value="10">
Start Timer
<div id="timer3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.timer {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #73AD21;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  function myTimer(resultDivId) {
    var currentVal = $("#"+ resultDivId).parent().attr("value");
    currentVal--;
    if(currentVal == 0) {
       var timerObj = $("#"+ resultDivId).parent().attr('timerObj');
       clearInterval(timerObj);
    }
    $("#"+ resultDivId).html(currentVal);
    $("#"+ resultDivId).parent().attr("value",currentVal);
  }

  $(".timer").click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('started') == "false") {
      var currentDivId = $(this).children('div').prop("id"); 
      var timerObj = setInterval(function(){ myTimer(currentDivId) }, 1000);
      $(this).attr('started','true');
      $(this).attr('timerObj',timerObj);
    }
    else {
       var timerObj = $(this).attr('timerObj');
       clearInterval(timerObj);
    }
  });
});
```

The timer will start when you click on div. It will stop if you click the div second time. You can also set separate count down for each div.